SQL Query Returning All Subjects Instead of Specified Subject in Exam Results
I have a query that is supposed to return the scores of students for a specific subject in an exam. However, the query is returning the scores for all subjects instead of just the specified subject.

These are some of the sample data and tables:
CREATE TABLE `exam_groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exam_type` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;


INSERT INTO `exam_groups` (`id`, `name`, `exam_type`, `description`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'PRE-NURSERY EXAMINATION', 'prekg_system', 'This section contains all examinations pertaining to the pre-nursery section', 0, '2022-11-21 19:11:56', NULL),
(2, 'KG EXAMINATION', 'kg_system', 'This is a section that contains examinations related to KG school', 0, '2022-11-21 19:12:19', NULL),
(3, 'PRIMARY EXAMINATION', 'primary_system', 'This section contains all examinations for Primary Secondary School.', 0, '2023-05-26 14:30:09', NULL),
(4, 'JSS  EXAMINATION', 'jss_system', 'This section contains all examinations for Junior Secondary School.', 0, '2022-11-21 19:13:33', NULL),
(5, 'SSS EXAMINATION', 'sss_system', 'This section contains all examinations for Senior Secondary School.', 0, '2022-11-21 19:14:04', NULL);

CREATE TABLE `exam_group_class_batch_exams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exam` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `passing_percentage` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sch_open` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `next_term_begin` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documents` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `exam_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_first` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_firstmid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_sec` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_secmid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_third` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_thirdmid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `use_exam_roll_no` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `is_publish` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `is_rank_generated` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `exam_group_class_batch_exams`
--

INSERT INTO `exam_group_class_batch_exams` (`id`, `exam`, `passing_percentage`, `session_id`, `sch_open`, `next_term_begin`, `documents`, `date_from`, `date_to`, `exam_group_id`, `is_first`, `is_firstmid`, `is_sec`, `is_secmid`, `is_third`, `is_thirdmid`, `use_exam_roll_no`, `is_publish`, `is_rank_generated`, `description`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(8, 'FIRST MID-TERM EXAMINATION', NULL, 17, '110', '2ND MAY, 2023', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 'Mid-term examination for first term.', 1, '2023-04-07 15:07:14', NULL),
(9, 'FIRST MID-TERM EXAMINATION', NULL, 17, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 'Mid-term examination for first term.', 1, '2022-10-20 21:05:03', NULL),

CREATE TABLE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exam_group_class_batch_exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_session_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roll_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `no_atten` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_abs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `teacher_remark` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `principal_remark` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `exam_group_class_batch_exam_students`
--

INSERT INTO `exam_group_class_batch_exam_students` (`id`, `exam_group_class_batch_exam_id`, `student_id`, `student_session_id`, `roll_no`, `no_atten`, `no_abs`, `teacher_remark`, `rank`, `principal_remark`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(3, 8, 4816, 7155, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, '2022-10-08 15:18:38', NULL),
(4, 8, 4847, 7332, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, '2022-10-08 15:18:38', NULL),

CREATE TABLE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subjects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exam_group_class_batch_exams_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_from` date NOT NULL,
  `time_from` time NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `room_no` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_marks` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_marks` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_hours` float(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `date_to` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subjects`
--

INSERT INTO `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subjects` (`id`, `exam_group_class_batch_exams_id`, `subject_id`, `date_from`, `time_from`, `duration`, `room_no`, `max_marks`, `min_marks`, `credit_hours`, `date_to`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(91, 8, 116, '2022-08-25', '10:13:01', '0', '', 1.00, 1.00, 0.00, NULL, 0, '2022-08-25 09:14:02', NULL),
(92, 8, 43, '2022-08-25', '10:13:05', '0', '', 1.00, 1.00, 0.00, NULL, 0, '2022-08-25 09:14:02', NULL),

CREATE TABLE `exam_group_exam_results` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exam_group_student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attendence` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `get_ca1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `get_ca2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `get_ca3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `get_ca4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `get_ca5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `get_ca6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `get_exam` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `get_tot_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rem1` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `rem2` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `note` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `get_marks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `exam_group_exam_results`
--

INSERT INTO `exam_group_exam_results` (`id`, `exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id`, `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`, `exam_group_student_id`, `attendence`, `get_ca1`, `get_ca2`, `get_ca3`, `get_ca4`, `get_ca5`, `get_ca6`, `get_exam`, `get_tot_score`, `rem1`, `rem2`, `note`, `get_marks`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(863, 35, 115, NULL, 'present', 8, 10, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 26, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-10-25 08:20:27', NULL),
(864, 44, 115, NULL, 'present', 10, 10, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 30, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-10-25 08:20:27', NULL),

CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'no',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `subjects`
--

INSERT INTO `subjects` (`id`, `name`, `code`, `type`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(39, 'AGRICULTURAL SCIENCE', 'AGRIC', 'Theory', 'no', '2019-09-29 17:34:11', '0000-00-00'),
(43, 'BASIC SCIENCE & TECHNOLOGY', 'B.S.T', 'theory', 'no', '2022-12-13 12:54:23', '0000-00-00'),

Here’s the query I’m using:
SELECT DISTINCT
    es.student_id AS exam_student_id,
    s.firstname AS student_firstname,
    s.lastname AS student_lastname,
    sub.name AS subject_name,
    eca.get_ca1 AS ca1_marks,
    eca.get_ca2 AS ca2_marks,
    eca.get_ca3 AS ca3_marks,
    eca.get_ca4 AS ca4_marks,
    eca.get_ca5 AS ca5_marks,
    eca.get_ca6 AS ca6_marks,
    eca.get_exam AS exam_marks,
    eca.get_tot_score AS total_score,
    eca.rem1 AS remark1,
    eca.rem2 AS remark2
FROM
    exam_group_class_batch_exam_students es
JOIN
    exam_group_class_batch_exams egcbe ON es.exam_group_class_batch_exam_id = egcbe.id
JOIN
    exam_group_class_batch_exam_subjects egcbes ON egcbe.id = egcbes.exam_group_class_batch_exams_id
JOIN
    subjects sub ON egcbes.subject_id = sub.id
JOIN
    exam_group_exam_results eca ON es.id = eca.exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id
JOIN
    students s ON es.student_id = s.id
JOIN
    student_session ss ON s.id = ss.student_id
JOIN
    classes c ON ss.class_id = c.id
JOIN
    sections sec ON ss.section_id = sec.id
JOIN
    exam_groups eg ON egcbe.exam_group_id = eg.id
WHERE
    ss.session_id = 19 
    AND c.id = 12 
    AND sec.id = 6
    AND sub.id = 43  -- Filtering by the specific subject ID
    AND eg.id = 4 
    AND egcbe.id = 80
ORDER BY
    s.lastname, s.firstname, sub.name;

Problem:
Even though I have specified the subject ID in the WHERE clause (sub.id = 43), the query still returns scores for all subjects instead of just the subject with ID 43.
What I've Tried:
Ensured that the JOIN conditions correctly associate the subject ID with the exam results.
Added the DISTINCT clause to avoid duplicate records, but the issue persists.
Expected Behavior:
The query should only return the results for the subject with sub.id = 43.
Actual Behavior:
The query returns results for all subjects, not just the specified subject.
Question:
What might be causing this issue, and how can I modify my query so that it only returns results for the specified subject?

Please add representative sample data and table definitions as text so that we can reproduce your issue.

@P.Salmon done. please check!

The issue with the query lies in the join between exam_group_class_batch_exam_subjects (egcbes) and exam_group_exam_results (eca).
Here's why:
I was filtering by subject ID (sub.id = 43) in the WHERE clause, but the join between egcbes and eca isn't explicitly based on the subject.
This means the eca table might include results for students in the same exam even if they are for different subjects.
So I just Modified the join between egcbes and eca to include a condition on exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id:
OIN exam_group_exam_results eca ON es.id = eca.exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id
  AND egcbes.id = eca.exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id

That solved it. I didn't catch it earlier on.
